# NSMutableArray: replaceObjectAtIndex vs assignment

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *array;
```

Which holds a number of objects.

Which one of the following should i use:

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject:anObject];
```

vs:

```
array[10] = anObject
```

in the ARC environment?

Edit:
I assume `replaceObjectAtIndex:` method would send a release method in Manual Reference Counted environment, whereas direct assignment would not. So would it be confusing the the ARC compiler, if i use direct assignment?

Comment: Why do you think there's any imperative ("should") about it? Use whichever you prefer. They are basically equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between these two approaches.

The [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#array-style-subscripting) explains that array-style subscripting for writing (assignment) translates to a call to `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:`.

So, from your example, `array[10] = anObject;` translates to:

```
[array setObject:anObject atIndexedSubscript:10];
```

This matters because setObject:atIndexedSubscript: *behaves differently* than replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/setObject:atIndexedSubscript:) of setObject:atIndexedSubscript: explains the difference (emphasis mine):

> If the index is equal to count the element is **added** to the end of the
>   array, **growing the array**.

In your example, if `array` is of size 10, then the expression `array[10] = anObject;` is valid; it will grow your array and add the object to the end. However, if instead you call `[array replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject:anObject];`, an `NSRangeException` exception will be thrown.

With regards to which method to use in an ARC environment, I think that's the wrong question to ask. The difference between the two is not ARC-dependent, so your decision should be based on intended behavior (and possibly style).

Comment: +1 with curious note. The Clang documentation you linked contradicts Apple's class docs, saying "assigning to an element using an index outside [the range `[0, array.count)`] will raise an exception; no syntax is provided for inserting, appending, or removing elements for mutable arrays". The range is "open" on the right, indicating that `count` is not valid. I agree that Apple's class reference is authoritative in this case, though.

Comment: @KenThomases, I agree with you. To me, it even seems that part of Apple's documentation contradicts *itself*. The parameter requirements are *exactly* the same for both methods, claiming "The index of the object to be replaced. This value must not exceed the bounds of the array. Important: Raises an NSRangeException if index is beyond the end of the array.".

It's only in the discussion section for setObject:atIndexedSubscript: that Apple's documentation clarifies any difference, which I find strange.

Comment: @nklauza The reason behind my question is that, i assume replaceObjectAtIndex: method used to send a release message to the object, in MRC and assignment does not. I'm not aware if the array holds a strong or weak reference to its objects, in ARC, and i'm not sure if a direct assignment would lead to ARC automatically releasing it, or confusing it.

Comment: @Alterecho, [arrays](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html) hold strong references to objects. Also, the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) indicate that "collections own the objects they contain" and that a "collection will relinquish ownership when the object is removed from the collection or when the collection is itself released". I suspect that setObject:atIndexedSubscript: behaves the same as replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: when index < count.

Comment: I looked for a while and I unfortunately cannot find any concrete documentation about that suspicion. [This](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/test/subscripting.m) possible test code kind of hints at it.

Comment: Cocoa memory management makes memory management a local concern. That is, each unit of a program (a class, a function, or a method) is responsible for its memory management and not responsible for other units. You can (and must) assume that Cocoa arrays do the right thing for their memory management. It is inconceivable that `-setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` doesn't do proper management of the object being removed from the array and the object being stored in the array (even if it's the same object). In any case, it's not the responsibility of client code such as yours.

Comment: @Alterecho, there's no direct assignment going on here. There's a method invocation that *looks* like an assignment. It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @KenThomases If it is indeed invoking the method, instead of the apparent assignment (which nklauza also claims), then it clears up my doubt. Till someone can claim concretely, that something equivalent to release is being called with the apparent assignment, i'll leave the question open. Thank you, both of you.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you for explaining so eloquently what I wanted to say but couldn't figure out how to. I wasn't sure that stating such things without also providing documentation to back it up would stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: @Alterecho By "claim concretely", do you mean provide a link to official documentation that explicitly says so?

Comment: @Alterecho If so, I don't believe *official* documentation exists that directly states `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` calls release; instead, there are docs to define the language, compiler and frameworks that--when combined--allow us to infer it. I've provided links to authoritative docs that say collections own the objects they contain, that said ownership is relinquished when an object is removed (e.g. replaced), and that array subscripting translates to a method that does such a replacement. The method is in the Foundation framework, so it must adhere to the aforementioned memory mgmt.

Comment: @nklauza Actually, i was looking for a document that states that the assignment translates to method calls. I found it here:http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html . Please do add it to your answer.

Comment: @Alterecho The second sentence in my original answer links to that same page (with a shortcut to the most relevant section). I used markdown to style the link, so perhaps it was not obvious.